# Compare two arrays remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I'm building management system with three roles (admin,supervisor,basic) on the user assignment page which would be a checklist where an admin can assign a basic user to a supervisor.

I have two arrays, the first array is supervisors that have been assigned to "manage" that specific basic user, and the second would be just all supervisors. My goal is to remove the already assigned supervisors from the all supervisor array.

//example

```
$supervisors['all'] = [
         ['id'=>'1','first'=>'john','last'=>'doe'],
         ['id'=>'2','first'=>'jane','last'=>'doe']
];
$supervisors['assigned'] = [
         ['id'=>'2','first'=>'jane','last'=>'doe']
];
```

//so the result I'm looking for is

```
$supervisors['all'] = [
         ['id'=>'1','first'=>'john','last'=>'doe'],
];
$supervisors['assigned'] = [
         ['id'=>'2','first'=>'jane','last'=>'doe']
];
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP code? In PHP there is a `=>` (not a `:`) operator for key-value assigning.

Comment: @ksimka Haha yea, I've written to much JSON lol I'll update it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `array_filter`.

```
// here we collect all the "assigned" ids in a plain array
$assignedSvsIds = array_column($supervisors['assigned'], 'id');
// then use it in a filter function
$supervisors['all'] = array_filter(
    $supervisors['all'], 
    function($sv) use ($assignedSvsIds) {
        // if id is in 'assigned', it'll be filtered out, otherwise - kept
        return !in_array($sv['id'], $assignedSvsIds, true);
    }
);
```